# Asymptotics of inverse Laplace transform of a function with an essential singularity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, special-functions, improper-integrals

Let $h$ be the function
$$ h(x) = \sum_{k\geq0} \frac{(ix)^k}{k!}\zeta(2k), $$
with the Laplace transform
$$ \tilde h(s) = -\frac{\pi}{2s}\sqrt{i/s}\cot\left(\pi\sqrt{i/s}\right), $$
which has an essential singularity at $s=0$.

How can I derive an asymptotic form for $h$ in the limit $x\to\infty$ ($x$ real)? I would like to understand how to do it with the inverse Laplace transform. The inversion formula gives
$$ -\frac{\sqrt{x}}{4i} \int \sqrt{i/s} \cot\big(\pi\sqrt{ix/s}\big) e^s\frac{ds}{s}, $$
with the integral taken along a vertical line in the right half-plane.

But the essential singularity at $s=0$ looks rather tricky to deal with and I am not sure how to approximate the integral. Heuristic semi-rigorous reasoning is welcome.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.emis.de/journals/BMMSS/pdf/v25n1/v25n1p6.pdf